# Conditional series convergence guess; Prove/ Disprove

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I ran into this question:

Prove or disprove:

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ is a converging series, but the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}^2$ diverges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ is conditionally convergent.

I'm pretty sure it's true because I couldn't find any example that shows otherwise, but still, i can't find the proof.

Thanks in advance,

Yaron.

Comment: Hint: If $\sum|a_n|$ converges, then $\sum a_n^2$ converges (by the Comparision Test).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to show that: if the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}^2$ diverges  then the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n}|$ diverges.

To prove this use that $a^2_n<1$ for all $n>N$ for some $N\in\mathbb N$ and therefore $|a_n|>a_n^2$ for all $n>N$...

Comment: no, thi is not what we want to show.

Comment: @user76508 Yes it is. (Note that P. implicitly made use of the convergence of $\sum a_n$ to show that $a_n^2<1$ for almost all $n$)

Comment: @user76508 It actually *is* what you're trying to show; since divergence of the sum absolute values is definition of conditional convergence (of course, assuming the original series converges).